# Xilinx UART simulation

Tags: tcl, vhdl, simulation, xilinx, uart

Just started to use Vivado 2016.1
1. What is considered as simulation of a circuit?
2. what steps i follow to make a circuit simulation?

Thank you

Comment: [basic_uart-20130424.zip (3 KB)](http://www.bealto.com/fpga-basic-uart-src.html) Contains basic_uart.vhd, constraints.ucf and t_serial.vhd from [FPGA Simple UART](http://www.bealto.com/fpga-uart_echo.html) by Eric Bainville - Apr 2013.  You're apparently asking someone to author a method to test  a third party's VHDL code.

Comment: could you please elaborate? If it's illegal i will delete it, i am student and find this on internet.

Comment: [Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: [UG900 Logic Simulation](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation.pdf), [UG894 Using Tcl Scripting](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/ug894-vivado-tcl-scripting.pdf), [XAPP199 Writing Efficient Testbenches](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp199.pdf). Your links don't work, consider asking specific questions. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).